# Calling Javascript Functions In Order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a button to perform an API Call to Flickr, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#goButton').click(function (){
         makeAPICall();
    });
});
```

This works as expected, but the communication between the client and the Flickr API takes a while to execute, so the page appears like it is hung. I would like to add a "Working Notice" that is displayed immediately on button click to let the user know that their action is processing.

To do this, I added an H1 tag:

```
<h1 id="notice"></h1>
```

and a function that changes the inner HTML to display a notice:

```
function workingNotice() {
    document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML="I am getting your results";
}
```

But when I try to edit the code for the button to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#goButton').click(function (){
         workingNotice();
         makeAPICall();
    });
})
```

The Working Notice is never displayed until the API Call has completed, which defeats the purpose.

I then tried using:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#goButton').click(function (){
         $.when(
             workingNotice()
         ).then(
             makeAPICall()
         );
    });
})
```

This gives the exact same results, where the Working Notice is not called until the API Call completes. Is there any alternative that I can try to force the order of these functions to comply?

UPDATE/EDIT:

While I found the solution to the initial problem in another answer, I know there's a reasonable chance the delay in the API Call processing is due to some mistake in this function. Here is the code for makeAPICall:

```
//call Flickr api and look for tags matching user search term
function makeAPICall(){

//get value tag from team 1 search box
var searchTag1 = escape(document.getElementById("searchTag1").value);
//get value tag from team 2 search box
var searchTag2 = escape(document.getElementById("searchTag2").value);

//build api call url with searchTag1
var url1 = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?" 
            + "method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXX&tags=" 
        + searchTag1 + "&sort=interestingness-desc" 
                + "&safe_search=1&has_geo=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
//build api call url with searchTag1
var url2 = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?"
                + "method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXX&tags=" 
        + searchTag2 + "&sort=interestingness-desc"
                + "&safe_search=1&has_geo=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";

//make call to flickr api
$.when(
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: url1,
      async: false,
      success : function(callReturn1) {
        callData1 = callReturn1;
        numResults1 = parseInt(callData1.photos.total);
      }
    }),
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: url2,
      async: false,
      success : function(callReturn2) {
        callData2 = callReturn2;
        numResults2 = parseInt(callData2.photos.total);
      }
    })
).then(
    drawChart()
);
```

}

Note "callData1", "callData2", "numResults1" & "numResults2" are all global.

Comment: Why is your api call hanging? Isn't is asychronous?

Comment: Actually the order of your functions SHOULD be respected at execution time. Could you perhaps post the full source code?

Comment: Can you post `makeAPICall`?

Comment: Posted makeAPICall, though I pulled my API Key out of the url to avoid having it posted publicly.

Comment: `async: false` is generally (pretty much always) the wrong solution to the async problem. You'll be better off restructuring to work with the async nature of ajax. It looks like you already understand deferred objects, so you shouldn't need to resort to sync calls.

Comment: Good point, I was using sync calls prior to setting this up to use deferred objects. Should be able to remove that now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  your makeAPICall is not async - call it out of bounds:

```
     workingNotice();
     setTimeout(makeAPICall, 1);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Now I'm going to go look up setTimeout() and figure out why it worked!